# Android Studio not working after Reinstall

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've been having some struggles with building my app after Reinstalling Android Studio.  The cues I've gotten have been related to either Java location or installation.  With the jre already installed it seems more likely not to be an issue with JAVA.

I've tried importing my project, copy and pasting from .txt files, reinstalling java, redefining java PATH, changing build dependencies, downloading command line sdk manager to build outside of the ide, erasing build caches, and I also let Android Studio rewrite properties.profile when importing Android Studio Project.

Another strange thing, when I create a directory in the project structure it shows up when the ide is initiating before gradle builds.  After gradle builds the folder is no longer visible.

***EDIT***

error: package R does not exist
error: cannot find symbol class appcompat

***UPDATE***

This seems like a common problem.  I've tried to follow most of the current questions on java incompatiblity but still haven't come up with a work around.  I downloaded oracle's jdk (unnecessarily) and pointed the studio project at it.  Created a shortcut using the jdk java.exe and placed it in Studio core, added java to the ***PATH*** which allowed ***gradlew build*** in the terminal to initiate but not complete.  What are the next steps?

***UPDATE***

Just in case somebody else stumbles onto this. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986301/package-r-does-not-exist) post and also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22275855/package-r-does-not-exist-error-when-building-with-gradle-from-command-line) got me there. 
 The fix ended up being an import of the .R file. ***com.example.android.recyclerview.R***  Hope it can help

Comment: It would be helpful to at least include the error (message) you encountered.

Comment: Did you reinstall the Android SDK?

Comment: I did current Android SDK: 8.0 (O) partial install; platform & google api... 7.0(Nougat) installed; platform, sources & google api...Build Tools; 25.0.3, 26.0.0, 26.0.1...Platform-Tools; 26.0.0...Constraint Layout 1.0.2...Solver 1.0.2...Tools 26.0.2...Android Repository 47.0...Google Repository 57

Comment: After successful Gradle build     IDE Fatal Errors   NullPointerException  during symbol building (rebuildModuleMaps)   I've assembled from the terminal with gradlew build, doesn't work anymore.  Could it be something to do with Android and Gradle plugins?

Comment: Yes, are you sure you have downloaded the correct SDK, BuildTools, ...? They need to be the same as the one you're building your app against. Otherwise it's not gonna work. But generally Android Studio gives you clues in the error messages