# error: package R does not exist after renaming package

Tags: android

I want to upload my app to Google play store. After uploading the signed `aab` file in `play console`, I got this error:

> You need to use a different package name because "com.example" is restricted.

So, I went to my `android studio` project and renamed my package. Now I constantly keep on getting the error:

> error: package R does not exist

I changed the `package name` in my manifest file, and also tried cleaning and rebuilding the project. But it's not working. How do I resolve this issue?

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RuL9.png)

If I use `com.example.electric_viewing.R` then it works. Why?

Comment: How did you change package name? You need to go in project view and then change package name from there so your error will resolve.

Comment: Yes I right clicked on package name and pressed `Refactor`, it changed the package name in all the files.

Comment: And build.gradle?

Comment: Yes, I changed there too. I even tried `invalidate cache and restart` but that too doesn't work

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22275855/package-r-does-not-exist-error-when-building-with-gradle-from-command-line